# Javascript sessionStorage Across tabs?

Tags: javascript, session-variables, session-cookies

I am using `sessionStorage` to ensure an action only happens once per session. However, if a user opens a new window - the `sessionStorage` is not carried over to the new window, and the action is executed again. See my code below:

```
if sessionStorage.alreadyTracked != "1"
  sessionStorage.alreadyTracked = "1"
  ...
```

Is there an easy way to do this that applies to all tabs? Maybe I need to use a cookie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as html5 storage goes i would go for localStorage in your case.

See below for the differences.

**Session Storage:**

- Values persist only as long as the window or tab in which they
  stored.
- Values are only visible within the window or tab that
  created    them.

**Local Storage:**

- Values persist window and browser lifetimes.
- Values are shared across every window or tab running at the same origin.

[Read more here](https://www.sitepoint.com/an-overview-of-the-web-storage-api/)

Comment: Did you know, that when you duplicate a tab (in chrome), the session store also is copied?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to switch to `localStorage` as `sessionStorage` is bound to individual tabs and `localStorage` is not.

Comment: Yeah but localstorage doesn't clean when browser shut down, and in some cases this is unwanted behavior (like with "authenticated" values)

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with targetting only FF/Chrome you might also want to take a look at the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API)

> The Broadcast Channel API allows simple communication between browsing contexts (that is windows, tabs, frames, or iframes) with the same origin (usually pages from the same site).