# how to clear sessionStorage across all tabs?

Tags: javascript, session, session-storage

I'm using React Js for my project. Is it possible to clear a value from sessionStorage in all tabs at once through 1 tab?

Some values are stored in sessionStorage and the requirement is to clear those sessionStorage values from all tabs.

Comment: You can communicate between windows using Storage Events or postMessage API and clear each session from it's own instance of your app

Comment: look at this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191848/javascript-sessionstorage-across-tabs/43191923 i will answer you q too!

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage doesn't persist in different tabs. Only local storage persists in different tabs, which can be cleared by localStorage.clear().

if you want to clear session storage use sessionStorage.clear().

Comment: Not always true, it does persist in different tabs if you duplicate a tab, and sessionStorage.clear() only clears one tab.